# Can Unity game file be embedded in WPF application using C# Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf

Can Unity game file be embedded in WPF Application using C# Visual Studio?
I need to embed unity 3D application in WPF using C# in visual studio.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I got solution to my question, below is the link, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati?msg=5013085#xx5013085xx

Answer (score 1):

As of Unity Patch 4.5.5p1, you can embed a windows standalone player into another application.

See the command line docs here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

There is also a sample here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/EmbeddedWindow.zip

Comment: How to send or pass data or values to the embedded unity 3d application from the Host WPF Application ?